# Webview failed to display when using embed url of Instagram

Tags: android, android-webview, instagram, embed

This is weird problem. When i using url like: https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs421mHgPM4/ this code is working to show Webview. But when i change to embed mode like this https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs421mHgPM4/embed/
My Webview not display anything. My code as follows:

```
public class WebReadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_frame)
    FrameLayout progressbarFrame;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar_line)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @BindView(R.id.webview_news)
    WebView webViewNews;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_reading);

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        //String urlData = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL_NEWS);
        String urlData = "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs421mHgPM4/embed";
        configureProgressbarLine();
        loadNewsByWeb(urlData);

    }

    private void loadNewsByWeb(String url) {

        webViewNews.setWebViewClient(new WebReadingClient());
        webViewNews.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewNews.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webViewNews.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webViewNews.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewNews.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webViewNews.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webViewNews.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webViewNews.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webViewNews, true);
        }

        webViewNews.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public static class WebReadingClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    }

}
```

and the layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebReadingActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        layout="@layout/appbar_layout" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview_news"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please give me some advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code i have tested with your url and its working fine,and this code have upload images in webview

```
    public class classname extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // Storage Permissions variables
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
    private WebView webView;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath = null;
    private long size = 0;

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have read or write permission
    int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || cameraPermission != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
  }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }
    try {
        String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:", "");
        File file = new File(file_path);
        size = file.length();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
        Integer count = 0; //fix fby https://github.com/nnian
        ClipData images = null;
        try {
            images = data.getClipData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) {
            count = data.getDataString().length();
        } else if (images != null) {
            count = images.getItemCount();
        }
        Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (size != 0) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                }
            }
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_web);
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    //if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration otherwise 
    activate software acceleration
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }



    webView.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs421mHgPM4/embed/");



    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    }
    ;
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the 
   default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }





    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    // For Android 5.0+
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, 
   WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUploadMessage = filePath;
        Log.e("FileCooserParams => ", filePath.toString());

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
     Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[2];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, "Select Files"), 
    1);

        return true;

    }
    }

public class PQClient extends WebViewClient {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
        if (url.contains("mailto:")) {

            // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            //Open links in new browser
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

            // Here we can open new activity

            return true;

        } else {

            // Stay within this webview and load url
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Show loader on url load
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // Then show progress  Dialog
        // in standard case YourActivity.this
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(classname.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    // Called when all page resources loaded
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                "document.getElementById('android-app').style.display='none';})()");

        try {
            // Close progressDialog
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }


    }
```

Comment: do I have to use the method found in PQChromeClient?

Comment: PQChromeClient for browsing images from webview. if u need to browse images from webview u can try that in your case you can use PQClient method to load url

Comment: better u can use this full code and it will works fine

Comment: Okay let me try it

Comment: is this answer helpfull @NandaZ

Comment: Yes it works, but actually i have other problem which still unsolved. Its when i put webviews in recycleview and the position of recycleview is below of other layout. Its still not showing instagram embed.But of course i have to make new question for it. I think it quit from topic question, even has same essential problem